# BizTalk custom functoid, that in some cases does not return value

Tags: biztalk

How can I develop custom functoid likes **Value Mapping**, that in some cases does not return value and mapped field will not be created?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: You can't.

More: A custom Functoid will always return a value because .Net method, at least within the scope of the Functoid API, will always return a value, even if that value is Null.

You only option is to test the return value after the custom Functoid with a Logical Functoid linked to the destination node.  This has the side effect of creating the destination node only of the Logical Functoid returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Why developing a custom functoid for that? You can use xslt to test the input value. If the value does not meets some requirements, don't create an output xml element. Take this example below, when the name does not exist for the person (on the source xml, map), the no xml element person should be created (on the destination xml, map)

```
<xsl:if test="person/name">
<be:person>
    <xsl:value-of select="person/name/text()" />
</be:person>
```

Try to use xslt for maps, and not functoids.